# QTP Web Service New Test Case return error: Exception from: System.Web.Services <HTML xmlns=''> was not expected

Tags: qtp

If I run a New QTP Web Service Test Case I get back the following error:

Exception from: System.Web.Services
 was not expected.

What is odd is I have existing test cases created by another tester that run fine. What is also odd is if I Copy (Save As) one of those test cases that work, clear everything out and recreate my test, it works.

I assume there is a setting I am missing for the new test case.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this issue?